# Hi, I have 209580 objects in an array, how to save all at once in MongoDB using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 209580 objects in an array, how to save all at once in MongoDB using mongoose?

Answer (score 0):

The better option would be to save the contents as CSV/JSON and import them directly.

This might be a help https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/bulk-import-a-csv-file-into-mongodb-using-mongoose-with-nodejs--cms-29574

Answer (score 0):

The [insert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/) of mongoDB (available through mongoose too) allows to insert array of items at once. According to the documentation you can send this kind of request:

```
Products.insert([
     { _id: 11, item: "pencil", qty: 50, type: "no.2" },
     { item: "pen", qty: 20 },
     { item: "eraser", qty: 25 }
   ], callback)
```

Answer (score 0):

Array containing the objects

var arr = [{ name: 'Star Wars' }, { name: 'The Empire Strikes Back' },...];

Use the `inertMany` method to save the objects in the array.
`Movies.insertMany(arr, function(error, docs) {})`

More Information can be found [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany)